# savePoint is not valid, and should be the result of a call to SaveTransactionPoint

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms, sqlite.net

```
 database.RunInTransaction(() =>
      {            
            if (dbVersion < DatabaseConstants.DATABASE_VERSION)
            {
                OnUpgrade();
              }
    });
        database.Commit();        
    }


  public void onUpgrade(){
     //inserting list of person
     database.RunInTransaction(() =>
           {
            //insert(TableNamePerson,PersonData)
            });
      database.Commit();


     database.RunInTransaction(() =>
        {
          //insert(TableNameContacts,ContactData)
       });
       database.Commit();        
    }
```

While using nested transactions, I am getting following exception:

savePoint is not valid, and should be the result of a call to SaveTransactionPoint

Answer (score 1):

From what I see in the documentation and the code, it might be intended behaviour. The `Action` specified for `RunInTransaction` is encapsulated as whole in an transaction. As SQLite only supports one transaction at a time, a new transaction is created if none exists, otherwise a save point is created within the already running transaction.

That said you don't have to call commit and you are not allowed to do it. `RunInTransaction` will take care for you. This is works fine with one block **but has some inconsistent behaviour with nested `RunInTransaction` blocks** as in your code. I would consider this as a bug.

In case of an exception the transaction as a whole is rolled back and thus terminated. That means even those blocks that have finished successfully will be rolled back! Every statement after an explicit or implicit `BEGIN`  is gone. Even if you have caught the inner exception, all outer `RunInTransaction` blocks will throw ArgumentExceptions:

```
savePoint is not valid, and should be the result of a call to SaveTransactionPoint
```

If you want to have more control you will need to work with explicit save points and `RollbackTo` instead of `Rollback`.

I have created a unit test to illustrate what happens:

```cs
[Test]
public void InsertItemIntoTable()
{
    using (var connection = Container.Resolve<IDatabase>().GetConnection())
    {
        var item1 = new Item { Id = 1, Description = "Test 1", Text = "Text for test 1" };
        var item2 = new Item { Id = 2, Description = "Test 2", Text = "Text for test 2" };
        var countAtStart = connection.Query<Item>("SELECT * FROM Item").Count;

        connection.RunInTransaction(() => // transaction started
        { 
            var saveTransactionPoint = connection.SaveTransactionPoint();
            connection.Insert(item2);
            // would fail as a commit would finish the transaction inside the action:
            // connection.Commit();

            // works as the transaction does not yet end
            connection.RollbackTo(saveTransactionPoint);
            Assert.IsTrue(connection.IsInTransaction);
        });
        Assert.IsFalse(connection.IsInTransaction);

        try
        {
            connection.RunInTransaction(() => // transaction started
            {
                connection.Insert(item1);
                var countAfter1stInsert = connection.Query<Item>("SELECT * FROM Item").Count;
                Assert.AreEqual(countAtStart + 1, countAfter1stInsert);
                connection.RunInTransaction(() => { connection.Insert(item2); });
                var countAfter2ndInsert = connection.Query<Item>("SELECT * FROM Item").Count;
                Assert.AreEqual(countAtStart + 2, countAfter2ndInsert);
                // bad SQL statement provokes an exception: no such table: bar. 
                try
                {
                    connection.RunInTransaction(() => // new save point within running transaction 
                    {
                        connection.Execute("SELECT foo FROM bar", "will throw exception");
                    });
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    // the whole transaction was rolled back already 
                    Assert.IsFalse(connection.IsInTransaction);
                    // that is why the outer block will fail next
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // outer RunInTransaction could not release its own save point and crashes with:
            // "savePoint is not valid, and should be the result of a call to SaveTransactionPoint"
        }

        var countAfterRollback = connection.Query<Item>("SELECT * FROM Item").Count;
        Assert.AreEqual(countAtStart, countAfterRollback);

        Assert.IsFalse(connection.IsInTransaction);
        // new transaction point start a deferred transaction as no transaction is running
        var point1 = connection.SaveTransactionPoint();
        Assert.IsTrue(connection.IsInTransaction);
        connection.Insert(item1);
        var point2 = connection.SaveTransactionPoint();
        connection.Insert(item2);
        var point3 = connection.SaveTransactionPoint();
        connection.Execute("INSERT INTO 'Item'('Id','Text','Description') VALUES (100,'Test 100',NULL);");
        connection.RollbackTo(point3);
        connection.RollbackTo(point2);
        // will commit the first insert i.e. item1, which implictily began a transaction
        connection.Commit();
        Assert.IsFalse(connection.IsInTransaction);
        var afterFinalRollback = connection.Query<Item>("SELECT * FROM Item").Count;
        // thus item1 has made it to the database
        Assert.AreEqual(countAtStart + 1, afterFinalRollback);
        // but not for ever ;)
        connection.Execute("delete from item where id > 0");
    }

}
```